# How do I set MarginTop property in javacode?

Tags: android

I created `LinearLayout` and `Button` via class not via XML. I know how to inflate layout view and button view dont know how to set margins of them. I need to set margins of my button and my linearlayout. If I use XML, it is very simple: `<android:marginLeft="10px">`.

But, what should I do if I want to set margin by class not by XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this we have linear layout in main.xml named lyt1 and we add edittext at runtime and set 
left margin value

please use bleow code :

```
lyt = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lyt1);
    EditText txt = new EditText(WvActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.leftMargin = 10;
    txt.setLayoutParams(lp);
    lyt.addView(txt);
    lyt.invalidate();
```

Comment: you can use lp.topMargin property as well

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```